# Load data into view via ajax from db in Laravel 4

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4

So far I have a User view that contains a typehead input box and a button.

I can manage to get the id of the selected user and display it when clicking on the button:

```
$('#load').bind('click', function(e)
{
   alert(selected);
});
```

Now I want to retrieve the data for the selected user from the database and display it in the User view. Here is my jQuery, route and controller:

```
var details = '<?php echo URL::to('details'); ?>';
$.getJSON(
    details, 
    function(data) 
    {
        $('#details').html(data);
    }
);

Route::get('details', 'HomeController@Details');

public function Details()
{
    $data = array('name' => 'Ste');
    return View::make('user')->nest('details', $data);
}
```

I've read multiple articles of AJAX in Laravel but am no closer to getting this working.
Does anyone know of a good tutorial for doing this or am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any error?what happens when you run your app?

Comment: I think `$.getJSON` is used to *Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request*, but you are sending HTML/TEXT data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Took me a while to figure out, but this is what I've ended up with.
This simply returns some html constructed in a view from a database query based on a single value (userid) passed into a controller method via jQuery ajax.
Eg: The user uses Bootstrap Typeahead to select a user, then (via ajax) gets the user's details from the database and displays then.

### The AJAX:

```
var details = '<?php echo URL::to('details'); ?>';
$.ajax(
{
    url: details,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {id: selected}, 
}).done( 
    function(data) 
    {
        $('#details').html(data);
    }
);
```

### The Controller:

```
public function Details()
{
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $user = DB::table('Users')->where('UserID', $id)->get();
    $data = array('user' => $user);

    return View::make('details', $data);
}
```

### The View:

```
@foreach($user as $person)
<label class="key">User ID</label>
<label class="data">{{ $person->UserID }}</label>

<label class="key">Person</label>
<label class="data">{{ $person->FullName, $person->Email, $person->WebSite }}</label>
@endforeach
```

### Notes:

- All my views are blade templates.
- My details view cannot inherit from another template (no extends('master')), this stops the view from working (no idea why).
- I'll only ever be returning 1 record, I use @foreach to access the array and turn each element into an object (there may be a better way of doing this).

Answer (score 3):

When you're using geJson you're expecting a json response, so you'll nee to use $.ajax() instead.

Another solution is to return

```
return Response::json(['view' => View::make('user')->nest('details', $data)]);
```

And then

```
$.getJSON(
    details, 
    function(data) 
    {
        $('#details').html(data.view);
    }
);
```

Comment: If I return "return Response::json(array('view' => '<input />'));" from my controller I can get the input box to appear, but as soon as I use "return Response::json(array('view' => View::make('details', data)));" I get nothing, any idea why?

Comment: Response::json(array('view' => View::make('details', $data)));
You forgot to add $ to the variable data

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo, I have actually got "return Response::json(array('view' => View::make('details', $data)));".

Comment: @SteB - I realise this is a slightly late response, but the reason you get nothing when doing `return Response::json(array('view' => View::make('details', $data)));` is because View::make returns an object, not just the content. To return a view directly, it can be simply done by: `return View::make('details', $data);` and then just placed the `data` in the jQuery into the HTML (instead of data.view). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what SteB is saying. To not use @foreach, if you only have/need 1 record, you should do this instead:

```
 $user = DB::table('Users')->where('UserID', $id)->first();
```

and then in your view you should be able to reference $user directly and not need a @foreach loop. This is a better way since it's one record you are retrieving.